# How can i remove part of a directory in batch?

Tags: java, batch-file

Here's the code

```
SET PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin"
dir *.java /b /s >> ./sources_list.txt
javac -cp ".;lib/*" @sources_list.txt -d compiled
dir compiled\*.class /b /s >> .\classes_list.txt
jar cfm app.jar MANIFEST.MF @classes_list.txt
del sources_list.txt
del classes_list.txt
PAUSE
```

so this is for compiling my java code (1st 3 lines) which works, then to copy the compiled classes into my jar using jar
now my problem is on line 4, finding the compiled classes and printing the path to the classes_list.txt, that works however it returns the full C:\somethin\compiled\something.class
i need it to return only the 
compiled\subfolders\something.class
how can i edit that to return the path i need?

Comment: offtopic - You should prefer using better tools for build.  Ant, gradle etc are easy to setup and use.

Comment: yea, i was mainly seeing if i could do it manually, because i like doing things my own way without using ant or others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jar command can take path to classes and create directory. You need to pass only the directory not all classes.

```
jar cfm app.jar MANIFEST.MF  compiled
```

should work.